# Picasso does not call onBitmapLoaded

Tags: android, bitmap, callback, picasso

My question is exactly similar to [Callback weird behaviour (Android, Picasso library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843055/callback-weird-behaviour-android-picasso-library). The problem is I try their solution but it has not worked for me. To be clear I am calling

```
Picasso.with(mActivity).load(mImageUrl).into(mTarget);
```

for whatever reason the `onPrepareLoad` method is being called but not the `onBitmapLoaded` method. How might I fix this issue?

In case it's not obvious, I know my onPrepareLoad method is being called because of

```
@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
  Log.i(TAG, "onPrepareLoad");
}
```

By the way, I have `Log.i` in each of the methods, only `onPrepareLoad` is being called.

============================================

Basically I had previously called

```
Picasso.with(mActivity).load(mImageUrl).resize(imgWidth, imgHeight).into(myImageView);
```

Then later if the image is not present, I make the call with the `Target` since at that point, the image is necessary.

**Also** I already tried taking out the "previous" call, leaving it for when just I need -- no change.

Comment: did try using anonymous Target class?

Comment: @Shaz of course. It's what didn't work -- which led me to find the answer quoted above. Which also didn't work.